# htaccess rewrite rule needed for example.com/xxx/xxx

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need a rewrite rue to redirect below

```
www.example.com/45678/2323
```

to below

```
www.example.com/view_basket.php?order_id=45678&pin=2323
```

I'm using below code but it seems there is a problem with base URL as when I'm suing this rewrite rule images on my page are not loading, images on my page has simple relative path like below

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

or

```
<img src="folder/image.jpg">
```

Here is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view_basket.php?order_id=$1&pin=$2 [L]
```